# Python - Getting offsets of packets (dpkt)

Tags: python

I have a sample pcap file, and I need to store offsets of each packet in a list. 
If I do this:

```
for ts, pkt in dpkt.pcap.Reader(f):
    mylist.append(f.tell())
```

I get the first value in the list as '114' which is actually the offset of the 2nd packet. I suppose in the first iteration, the file pointer has moves to the 2nd packet as soon as it stores values in `ts` and `pkt`.

Is there a way of getting the offset the packets properly?

Another way out might be if the Global Header of a Pcap file is has fixed size, then I can simply use that value as the first value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global header of a Pcap file has a fixed size of 24 bytes. The structure of the global header is as follows:

```
    typedef struct pcap_hdr_s {
        guint32 magic_number;   /* magic number */
        guint16 version_major;  /* major version number */
        guint16 version_minor;  /* minor version number */
        gint32  thiszone;       /* GMT to local correction */
        guint32 sigfigs;        /* accuracy of timestamps */
        guint32 snaplen;        /* max length of captured packets, in octets */
        guint32 network;        /* data link type */
} pcap_hdr_t;
```

You can refer to http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#Global_Header for more details.